# Docker run throws no such file or directory: unknown

Tags: scala, docker, sbt

I am trying to dockerize my application but I am running into following error when I run it:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/app/bin/app-core": stat /app/bin/app-core: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

But when I do a `sbt docker:publishLocal`, it works perfectly. I am using Windows 11 and running Docker desktop. Any ideas what might be the cause?

build.sbt:

```
docker / dockerfile := {
  val targetDir = "/app"

  new Dockerfile {
    from("openjdk:17")
    entryPoint(s"$targetDir/bin/${executableScriptName.value}")
    expose(8080)
  }
}

docker / buildOptions := BuildOptions(cache = false)
```

Dockerfile created by sbt-docker & sbt-native-packager:

```
FROM openjdk:17
ENTRYPOINT ["\/app\/bin\/app-core"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

When I do a sbt docker:publishLocal, it works perfectly. But when I do a build:

```
docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag app:test1
```

Then try to run it via:

```
docker run -itd -p 8080:8080 app-core:test1
```

Then it gives me the error above.

Comment: Your Dockerfile doesn't `COPY` anything into the image, so the `/app` directory won't exist there.  Are you using the [sbt-docker plugin](https://github.com/marcuslonnberg/sbt-docker)?  It looks like that has syntax to `copy()` build artifacts in.

Comment: Run `show dockerCommands` from the directory which contains your `build.sbt` file and include the output with your question. The output will show what SBT is adding to the Dockerfile

Comment: @DavidMaze When I add COPY 0/stage /app also to the Dockerfile then it fails with: Unknown desc = failed to compute cache key: "/0/stage" not found: not found